# Invoke cross account Lambda from Amazon EKS pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-eks

I have two aws account A- where I am running my EKS cluster from which I want to invoke a lambda function which is in another AWS account B, The k8s pod is java based micro-service which is responsible to invoke lambda which assume the EKS node's role.

I have  two IAM role , in account A I have role for eks node-group in which I have attached below policy along whit this it also has lambda_full access aws managed policy attached to it.
`{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID_B:role/Hull-Multi-Tenant-Role-Lambda" } }`

I account B I have role `Hull-Multi-Tenant-Role-Lambda` which has lambda_full access and in it's trust relation policy I have below json
`{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": { "AWS": [ "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A_ID:role/hull-nonprod-eks-node-role" ] } "Action": "sts:AssumeRole" } ] }`